# Unavailable hosted workbench in SPFX

Tags: spfx

I'm new to SPFX.

I'm moving the first steps following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/build-a-hello-world-web-part)

My packages

npm list --global --depth=0️

+-- @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.13.1
+-- gulp@4.0.2
+-- npm@6.14.15
`-- yo@4.3.0

After creating a web part and launching gulp serve the following request:

https://localhost:4321/_layouts/workbench.aspx

returns with a not found error.

Instead the request https://localhost:4321 returns a directory and file list.

What am I missing ?

I searched in my development folder and cannot find the layout directory nor workbench.aspx file

**UPDATE 1**

I executed *gulp trust-dev-cert*

Here is my serve.json:

```
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
"port": 4321,
"https": true,
"initialPage": "https://localhost:4321/_layouts/workbench.aspx"
}
```

In the local folder where I created the web-part should I find **workbench.aspx** ? I cannot find it anywhere on localhost.

Answer (score 2):

According to [SharePoint Framework v1.13 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/release-1.13) Workbench was removed. I lost hours on this problem ! SPFX is changing so fast that most tutorials are outdated !

Comment: "initialPage": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_layouts/workbench.aspx"

Answer (score 0):

please check ./config/serve.json and verify the port, http and initalpage parameter is correct

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Sagar Joshi
I updated my question with my serve.json

Comment: @Filippo can u please share error screenshot

Comment: @Filippo could you get any solution for this error? iI am also facing this error

Comment: @kl kl
You are forced to used Sahrepoint on line, you cannot use localhost any more., at least it is what I remember.

Comment: "initialPage": "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_layouts/workbench.aspx"