# Gulp serve is opening a webpage, but it shows page not found error

Tags: html, sharepoint, gulp, sharepoint-online, spfx

I am new to sfpx , I started with the intro videos on MS page, I did all the setups but when I run `gulp serve` it redirects me to "https://localhost:4321/index.html" but browser shows "this site can't be reached" , as well as there is no "index.html" in my local project path. Please help me with possible solutions for this.
Versions of different modules installed:

Node - v14.15.0

yo - 4.3.0

gulp - 4.0.2

npm - 6.14.8

I am using a gitpod instance for my development, as well as I have tried on my windows device, I got the same errors. Please let me know if any more files or info is required to solve this error then I can share them.
What I tried:
based on some blogs I added the environment variable "NODE_NO_HTTP2":1, but this did not solve the problem
Checked if the port "4321" is not being used by any other services.No service was using this port

This issue is completely the same/similar to this one "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433862/unavailable-hosted-workbench-in-spfx" but I couldn't find a solution over there so reposted my version
This is the `serve.json` file content:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/core-build/serve.schema.json",
  "port": 4321,
  "https": true
}
```

TIA

Answer (score 0):

The local workbench was deprecated in the latest version of the SPFx tools. You are supposed to use sharepoint online workbench to test your web part. Means, instead of `http://localhost:4321` navigate to:

`https://<yoursharepoint>.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx`

Maybe you could still use the local workbench using `gulp serve-deprecated` instead of `gulp serve` (if it works depends on the version of the SPFx you are using, but soon it won't). Just test on online SharePoint workbench (for that, you need to have online SharePoint of course)

Comment: Thanks , I dont have access to the real SharePoint web portal, I want to develop the app in my local environment (preferably linux device) , I tried the command "gulp serve-deprecated" but still I cant find the correct landing page generated in folder neither in the browser. What should I do? right now its spfx-1.13 being used, I will downgrade to lower version and try and inform you if it gets through

Comment: The "gulp serve-deprecated" should open the browser with the correct url with 1.12.1 it was working. But I would recommend you do simply register yourself and get the normal sharepoint (online).

Comment: I am still facing the issue, using 1.12.1 version and gulp serve-deprecated, can you have a look into this gitpod environment? https://gitpodio-templatetypescr-k3hqwtlnji5.ws-us31.gitpod.io  , let me know if you are able to access it or not, or else can we connect through email? my email id (hjkl8hjkl37@gmail.com)

Comment: Please use **generator** (@microsoft/generator-sharepoint) of version 1.12.1 to create new project of version 1.12.1, the local workbench (gulp serve-deprecated) does work with new project (https://localhost:5432/workbench is opened by default). Unfortunately, I am unable to access the link you provided.

Comment: To install yeoman generator 1.12.1: npm i -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@1.12.1 To create new project: yo @microsoft/sharepoint. The newer versions requires you to debug using sharepoint online workbench, and do neither install nor support the local workbench.